# Tile pattern for shower base using large porcelain format

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, tile, tiling

I am building 46x34 shower base using large format tile. I like it because it looks the same as the flooring. I building a curbless shower by the way.

However the plumber did not position the drain in the center so I came up with this tile pattern to offset the the larger width on the right side.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

However it came out not that great looking.

Do you have any recommendation?

(In case you ask, I have waterproof liner behind the hardiebacker AND Redgard. The tiles have not been set yet. I just lay them into correct position for now).

**Update**

Here is the result. It looks “okay” unless you get 1-2 feet close to it

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8toKO.jpg[image]

Comment: you have lots of compound slopes there. it will be tricky.

Comment: That looks like high-gloss tile to me, not a good choice for a shower floor.

Comment: @Jasen The slopes causing so many cuts so I couldn't get large pieces to lay. Mattman944 It is matte. I think some water on it so it looks shiny in the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're being too hard on yourself. So far, I think it looks great. Keep in mind that once you start setting the tiles in Thinset a lot of those uneven pieces will be OK. You'll also have uniform grout lines. If you start at the drain and work outward setting all the large tiles first, you'll be fine. You'll still have to cut or trim some of the tiles as you set them but that's to be expected. Your last tile on the lower right should be cut to match the one on the other side. Definitely think about using epoxy grout on this as it's much stronger. Smooth over those outside corners.
Also think about putting two coats of RedGard on all your wall surfaces in the shower.

Comment: Updated photo above

Comment: @HP Thanks for the update.  Looks pretty darn good from here.  I've seen "pro" jobs that didn't look this good.

Answer (score 0):

We used 12" tile squares in much of the house. The professional tile setter suggested laying them at 45 degrees in the smaller areas( bathrooms). I believe the angle looks much better for a large tile in a smaller area. It needed some cutting but not bad ; cutting the tiles for the sides at 45 , corner to corner. 
I then put 20" square tile in a 12 ft square room addition and a portico using the 45 angle cuts . It was not much extra work and looks good.